# with package in ~/quicklisp/local-projects it loads with asdf:require-system but not ql:quickload

Tags: common-lisp, quicklisp

I have a package redis-uop in ~/quicklisp/local-projects with asd file:

```
 (asdf:defsystem :redis-uop
  :description "Describe redis-uop here"
  :author "Your Name <your.name@example.com>"
  :license  "Specify license here"
  :version "0.0.1"
  :serial t
  :components ((:file "package")
               (:file "redis-uop"))
  :depends-on (:cl-redis))
```

This works fine as in title with asdf:require-system but not with ql:quickload.  The latter insists that cl-redis is not known despite the fact it is listed in quicklisp and explicitly loaded before I tried this.  I don't understand why this would be happening.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

Never mind.  I had inadvertently added cl-redis in the packages.lisp as well.  I don't remember why.  Removing that made it work.